# Page isn't getting redirected to as defined action CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have redirecting to

```
 $this->redirect(array('action' =>'index'));
```

in Cats controllers view action, but its redirecting to localhost/cats I want localhost/cats/index   can we do this ?

Comment: localhost/cats and localhost/cats/index are the very same (via routing). the latter is just overhead for CRUD since "/cats" already stands for index in CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to do this?
It's going to `localhost/cats` because cakePHP's routes tell it that index is the default action. You can probably remove/overwrite the rule in Config/routes.php that does this, however it's probably not necessary.